# Scaling a two-tier MEAN application with Docker on AWS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

So my current set-up is a Node.js application that serves up an Angular front-end, a second Node.js application that has Express and serves as an API, and a MongoDB instance. Simply, the client-side app talks to the back-end app and the back-end app talks to MongoDB.

I was looking into how to Dockerize these applications and it seems like some examples use linking. So my question is does linking only work on the same host (meaning a single EC2 instance on AWS) or multiple EC2 instances? If only the former and if I have both apps and Mongo containerized on one instance, how do I scale out? Like if I spin up a second EC2 instance, would I put both containerized Node apps and Mongo again on that second instance? Is having a Mongo container on the same instance with the Node apps a single point of failure? How is that fault tolerant?

Just trying to wrap my head around this and apologize for my ignorance on the subject. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should put each app as well as the MongoDB server in separate containers (which is what I think you intend) and the linking (via Docker-Compose or other method) is just networking. If you use Docker links, it creates a private network. You can create other networks to talk to each other, also to a LAN, WAN, whatever.

Yes, putting them all on the same EC2 instance is creating a SPOF.

If that's a concern, look into: https://docs.docker.com/swarm/networking/

> Docker Swarm is fully compatible with Docker’s networking features.
>   This includes the multi-host networking feature which allows creation
>   of custom container networks that span multiple Docker hosts.

Or load balance your apps and use an AWS-hosted MongoDB cluster. There are many possible approaches based on your needs and budget.